# Multiple definition of main in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I'm trying to generate a file `ppm2jpeg` from my sources in `./src` using my objects in `./obj` and `./obj_prof`. I also want to generate tests that I can execute independently in `./tests`.

Here's my Makefile in my main folder :

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -Iinclude -Ofast -pg
LDFLAGS = -lm -pg


SRC_FILES=$(wildcard src/*.c)



OBJ_FILES=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

OBJ_PROF_FILES = obj_prof/htables_prof.o

all: ppm2jpeg tests

ppm2jpeg: $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES)
    $(LD) $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

tests: $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES)
    make -C tests/

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


clean:
    rm -rf ppm2jpeg do_test $(OBJ_FILES)
    make -C tests/ clean
    rm -f $(wildcard images/*.bla)
    rm -f $(wildcard images/*.jpg)
```

And here's my Makefile in `./tests`:

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -I../include -O0 -g
LDFLAGS = -lm -pg

OBJ_FILES = $(wildcard ../obj/*.o)
OBJ_PROF_FILES = ../obj_prof/htables_prof.o


SRC_TESTS = $(wildcard *-test.c)
OBJ_TESTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_TESTS))
TESTS = $(patsubst %-test.c,%-test,$(SRC_TESTS))

all: $(TESTS)

%-test: %-test.o
    $(CC) -g $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES) $(OBJ_TEST) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%-test.o: %-test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm -c $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(TESTS)
CC = gcc
LD = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -I../include -O0 -g
LDFLAGS = -lm -pg

OBJ_FILES = $(wildcard ../obj/*.o)
OBJ_PROF_FILES = ../obj_prof/htables_prof.o

# Fichiers de test
SRC_TESTS = $(wildcard *-test.c)
OBJ_TESTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_TESTS))
TESTS = $(patsubst %-test.c,%-test,$(SRC_TESTS))

all: $(TESTS)

%-test: %-test.o
    $(CC) -g $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES) $(OBJ_TEST) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%-test.o: %-test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm -c $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(TESTS)
CC = gcc
LD = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -I../include -O0 -g
LDFLAGS = -lm -pg

OBJ_FILES = $(wildcard ../obj/*.o)
OBJ_PROF_FILES = ../obj_prof/htables_prof.o

# Fichiers de test
SRC_TESTS = $(wildcard *-test.c)
OBJ_TESTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_TESTS))
TESTS = $(patsubst %-test.c,%-test,$(SRC_TESTS))

all: $(TESTS)

%-test: %-test.o
    $(CC) -g $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_PROF_FILES) $(OBJ_TEST) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%-test.o: %-test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm -c $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(TESTS)
```

When I try to do that

```
/tests/example-test.c:5: multiple definition of `main'; ../obj/ppm2jpeg.o:ppm2jpeg.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that you are trying to link together two object files each containing a `main()` function.

Analyzing the error message, I would guess both `example-test.c` and `ppm2jpeg.c` define `main()`, which means you should not link `example-test.o` and `ppm2jpeg.o` in the same executable.

In your Makefile, you should probably make sure `OBJ_FILES` only lists files that don't define `main()`, so you should make sure it leaves out `ppm2jpeg.o`.

Comment: Thank you! I filtered out the ppm2jpeg.o in my Makefile in ./tests and everything's working now!